# How to sync Android device with eclipse

Tags: eclipse, android-emulator, synchronization

I have a Android device. How to sync with Eclipse for execute code directly in mobile not in emulator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just simply connect your phone via USB cable to your computer and run your application. Window pops up and you can choose then between connected devices. Make sure you enabled debugging mode in your device.